# How to delete subfolders from a 7zip archive?

Tags: command-line-interface, 7zip

I have several VS2010 project archives that were incorrectly including folders like `obj` & `bin`. I've tried to delete those subfolders using the following command but it does not work:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" d -r "d:\Backups\WorkShop\CNC WorkShop.zip" obj\\* bin\\*
```

I used the `-r` option in case a sub folder exists in multiple locations in the hierarchy.

How can I delete specific sub folders by name?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like dropping the asterisk `*` from your command [should do the trick](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/recurse.htm):

```
7z d archive.7z -r dir/
```

This recursively removes a subdirectory named `dir` from an archive `archive.7z`.